# How do I put my laptop as main screen with arandr?

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, external-monitor, randr

I'm using 64 bit Lubuntu 15.04, I inserted my monitor, opened `arandr`, activated the monitor and positioned it as shown below. Now the problem I'm having is that my monitor seems to be considered the main screen as it has my desktop icons and task bar. Now how do I move the bar (and the icons) to the bottom (laptop) screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the monitor where the task bar is positioned at, can be changed in the task bar's panel preferences. To the right you can see the monitor it is displayed at. Change the number to 2 and it changes monitors. This does not reposition your Desktop icons though.

Right click the task bar and click `Panel Settings > Geometry` to get to the preferences pane.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just drag and drop the monitor you want to make it as the default monitor to the first position then drag the other to be beside and not down, then press save

Comment: But I don't want the monitor to be to the right of my laptop. I want it to be above, as it is physically positioned. Is it impossible to do so?

Comment: you may try it. just move the screens as you like and test

Comment: I did and I want the screens to be positioned as in the screenshot above. The problem is that the bar goes to the monitor when I do so. It doesn't go back to the laptop's screen.

Comment: then you should need some more customization not only `arandr`